# Using private members and methods in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var test = function(id, company){
    //public members
    this.id = id;
    this.company = company;
    //private member
    var age = 24;
    //private method
    var getAge = function(){
       return this.age;
    };
    //public method
    this.displayAge = function(){
       console.log(getAge());
    }
}

//invoking 

var t = new test(1, 'XYZ Corp');

t.displayAge(); //undefined
```

Why is it not getting displayed

Comment: What you describe as "private members" are simple *local variables*. You won't be able to access them using `this`. Read http://stackoverflow.com/q/13418669/1048572

Answer (score 1):

It's not being displayed because `this.age` is undefined.  You want `age`.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the scope of variables in js

A variable is visible inside a function not outside

```
var a = "foo"
function fooBar () {
  var b = "bar"
  console.log(a) // foo
  console.log(b) // bar
}

console.log(a) // foo
console.log(b) // undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

You want this:

```
var test = function(id, company){
    //public members
    this.id = id;
    this.company = company;
    //private member
    var age = 24;
    //private method
    this.getAge = function(){
       return age;
    };
    //public method
    this.displayAge = function(){
       console.log(this.getAge());
    }
}

//invoking 

var t = new test(1, 'XYZ Corp');

t.displayAge(); //undefined
```

Note that both "getAge" and "displayAge" need to be attached to `this` but your private variable "age" should *not* be.